# Randomizing locations of css with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

It should randomize the location of a black circle when pressed but I can’t figure out why it isn’t working.

```js
function myFunction1(button) {
  var xPosition = math.floor(math.random() * 101) + '%';
  button.style.top = xPosition;
  var yPosition = math.floor(math.random() * 101) + '%';
  button.style.left = yPosition;
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="black circle" onclick="myFunction1(this)"></button>
```

Comment: `Math` not `math`. You also need to set the position property via CSS to something like relative or absolute in order for the `top` and `left` to matter

Comment: See above. But even with that fix you still won't see it work, for same reason that this doesn't work even if you don't use JS. Set a [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) and [left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) value on your CSS directly, to simulate "a single random location" and look at the result: what happens?

Comment: It’s working now thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Change math... to **M**ath..

And add this to css:

```
.circle {
  ...
  position: fixed;
}
```

Like this:

```js
function myFunction1(button) {
  var xPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + '%';
  button.style.top = xPosition;
  var yPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + '%';
  button.style.left = yPosition;
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="black circle" onclick="myFunction1(this)"></button>
```

Comment: If this helped you mark it correct.